# Using KDE's Dolphin file manager dual view the Norton Commander way?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, filemanager, dolphin

KDE's default file manager Dolphin offers a possibility of a dual view. I would like to define keyboard shortcuts to

- easily switch between the left and right panes
- copy/move files between them

but Dolphin seems to offer nothing of that sort out of the box. Has anybody had similar issues and figured a way to do that or around it? Maybe an alternative KDE software?

[image: Dolphin dual view]

Comment: The Krusader is an advanced twin panel (commander style) file manager for KDE: http://www.krusader.org/ . It is in the Ubuntu repositories: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=krusader&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the feature to quickly move between views  is not available.

See bug report @ https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=171743.